# How can I use media breakpoint to set number of columns in css

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, media-queries

I want my div element to displayed as a single column when the screen size is less than 537px

I don't want to use col-xs-** as the breakpoints are not where I want them.

I also don't want to use Less for this.

This is my CSS:

```
@media (max-width: 537px) {
.col-sm-12 {
width: 100%;
}
}
```

And here's my html:

```
<h1>PORTFOLIO</h1>
    <div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
        <img src="#" alt="#" width="100%">
         <p>Me</p>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
            <img src="#" alt="#" width="100%">
         <p>Me</p>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
                <img src="#" alt="#" width="100%">
         <p>Me</p>
        </div>


        <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
        <img src="#" alt="#" width="100%">
         <p>Me</p>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
            <img src="#" alt="#" width="100%">
         <p>Me</p>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
                <img src="#" alt="#" width="100%">
         <p>Me</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: are you using bootstrap or is this your own thing?

Comment: Using bootstrap

Comment: but don't want to use default breakpoints

Comment: add a bootstrap tag to it as well so you have a higher chance of finding the right people as well

Comment: If the breakpoints aren't where you need them, change them. If you need new breakpoints, add a class to each column, then use `@media (max-width: 537px) { .your-class { width: 100%; } }`

Comment: @Rob  I've changed my CSS but still showing 2 columns instead of one. Any ideas? My html: div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6" class="custom-column"

Comment: Combine your class attributes into one property - `<div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6 custom-class"></div>`

Comment: Still getting 2 columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this code**

```
<div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6 custom-class"></div>

@media (max-width: 537px) {
.custom-class {
width: 100% !important;
max-width:100% !important;
}
}
```